# copy and paste from one sheet to another without the formulas from the first page

Tags: vba, excel

This is simple in concept but hard for me to do in practice.

Ive got information on Sheet Separate range **A6** to **M65** and trying to paste all in information on Sheet Final into the first blank row without transferring all the formulas from Separate.

*Moves all information to final*

```
Worksheets("Seperate").Range("A6:K100").Copy Worksheets("Final").Range("A6")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PasteSpecial` function. Read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) details. You need to pass (probably) `xlPasteValues` as parameter.

```
Worksheets("Seperate").Range("A6:K100").Copy 
Worksheets("Final").Range("A6").PasteSpecial <put_here_parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code only copy  value of range.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim Target As Range

    Set Target = Worksheets("Final").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    vDB = Worksheets("Seperate").Range("A6:K100")
    Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
End Sub
```